# Is there a way to improve this ANTLR 3 Grammar for positive and negative integer and decimal numbers?

Tags: numbers, integer, decimal, grammar, antlr3

Is there a way to express this in a less repeative fashion with the optional positive and negative signs?

What I am trying to accomplish is how to express optionally provide positive `+` ( default ) and negative `-` signs on number literals that optionally have exponents and or decimal parts.

```
NUMBER : ('+'|'-')? DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* EXPONENT?
       | ('+'|'-')? '.'? DIGIT+ EXPONENT?
       ;

fragment 
EXPONENT : ('e' | 'E') ('+' | '-') ? DIGIT+ 
         ;

fragment
DIGIT  : '0'..'9' 
       ;
```

I want to be able to recognize `NUMBER` patterns, and am not so concerned about arithmetic on those numbers at that point, I will later, but I am trying to understand how to recognize **any** `NUMBER` **literals** where numbers look like:

```
123
+123
-123
0.123
+.123
-.123
123.456
+123.456
-123.456
123.456e789
+123.456e789
-123.456e789
```

and any other standard formats that I haven't thought to include here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: no, there is no way to improve this AFAIK. You could place `('+' | '-')` inside a fragment rule and use that fragment, just like the exponent-fragment, but I wouldn't call it a real improvement.

Note that unary `+` and `-` signs generally are not a part of a number-token. Consider the input source `"1-2"`. You don't want that to be tokenized as 2 numbers: `NUMBER[1]` and `NUMBER[-2]`, but as `NUMBER[1]`, `MINUS[-]` and `NUMBER[2]` so that your parser contains the following:

```
parse
  :  statement+ EOF
  ;

statement
  :  assignment
  ;

assignment
  :  IDENTIFIER '=' expression
  ;

expression
  :  addition
  ;

addition
  :  multiplication (('+' | '-') multiplication)*
  ;

multiplication
  :  unary (('*' | '/') unary)*
  ;

unary
  :  '-' atom
  |  '+' atom
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  NUMBER
  |  IDENTIFIER
  |  '(' expression ')'
  ;

IDENTIFIER
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | DIGIT)*
  ;

NUMBER 
  :  DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* EXPONENT?
  |  '.'? DIGIT+ EXPONENT?
  ;

fragment 
EXPONENT 
  :  ('e' | 'E') ('+' | '-') ? DIGIT+ 
  ;

fragment
DIGIT  
  :  '0'..'9' 
  ;
```

and `addition` will therefor match the input `"1-2"`.

### EDIT

An expression like `111.222 + -456` will be parsed as this:

[image]

and `+123 + -456` as:

[image]

Comment: @Jarrod, but how will you parse `1--2`? My suggestion handles this properly.

Comment: ... and `- 3` (minus space number)?

Comment: What does the definition of `NUMBER` in your example look like, I don't understand how it works without that example.

Comment: @Jarrod, yeah, that was a bit confusing. Added the lexer rules to my example.

Comment: ok, so how does that know that later when I create something that looks like `x = -123` that it is a `negative` number?

Comment: @Jarrod, I added a few rules to my example grammar.

Comment: @Bart ok thanks for the attention to detail I am starting to understand how your example works, declaring this stuff is kind of **upside down** thinking. But I still don't see how this matches `+123` as a stand alone term as in a `add(111.222, -456)`

Comment: And the function call is a straw man for how does your solution match my `NUMBER` anywhere in the text, not just in `addition`?

Comment: @Jarrod, see my edit how `add(111.222, -456)` would be parsed. But I don't quite understand your remark about the "function call" though...